# Icons are not shown and pictures lost quality after changing font in opencart

Tags: css, fonts, opencart, farsi

I'm using opencart in farsi language and I decided to change the font of my website. First I tried to change the font style in "body" element in css. But unfortunately it didn't work. Everything was done carefully, I used "font-face", uploaded fonts and everything. But it didn't work and I did this in main css file.
  
  * {
    font-family: something;
    }
After I did so, all of the pictures in the website have lost quality, and none of the icons are shown...

how can I fix it...?
Regards

Comment: try to reproduce it on a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Icons are not shown because you are overriding the font family.

Have a look at Glyphicons or Font-Awesome

http://fontawesome.io/

http://glyphicons.com/

They use a font to print the icons.

For the image quality I have no clue, try to restrict the range of your font override. Maybe it's a bug on the browser that gets angry if you set a font-familty to an img tag (I'm guessing)

Comment: dear Pietro, I have restored everything to past conditions. I mean I'm not using that piece of code anymore. But icons are not fixed. Should I clear the server's cache...??